# If Android is Linux under the hood, why do we need to root at all?

Tags: android, linux, root, android-source

When running Linux, you don't need to choose between a rooted or unrooted system; you just `sudo` or `su -`, type your password, and you get to run commands as root.

Why is Android different? Why do you have to flash a special version and jump through hoops just to root your phone?

My understanding is that Android runs Linux, so why can't the phone just prompt for your password when an app needs root access?

How does making it more complicated benefit the OS and the user, and why is it that a rooted phone doesn't prompt for a password to get root privileges, it just pops a question to grant or deny root privileges?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Please use other sites for non-programming Android questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Android *does* run on Linux, it merely means that it's using Linux as it's core.

First of all, a basic difference must be addressed - Linux in itself is just a kernel. It handles basic input/output systems, threading, power management etc...

Android, as such, uses only these parts of the GNU/Linux project. It uses a camera driver, bluetooth driver, display driver etc... (you get the idea)

On top of that, Android adds a set of useful libraries for font rendering, audio management, databases and such.

And only inside of those libraries is the Android Runtime (ART) which used to feature a Dalvik VM and now uses ART. So Android is able to "sandbox" a user within that runtime.

This is done on purpose, to prevent developers from executing malicious code on the Android system. Each app has a set of abilities to which it must comply. It's mostly a safety thing

EDIT: Update

Generally speaking, this is the "modern" OS approach that seems to be taking off as of late. Specifically - each app operates within it's own sandboxed environment and file system - which is inaccessible to others. To goal is to make "ordinary" users unable to run root access software. Since most security exploits are - in one way or another - user errors

Comment: Thanks, I heard this was a safety thing before, but I can't understand how it would jeopardize safety to have it behave the same way as a desktop: every app starts with the current user's permission and if they need to do something outside of this scope then it prompts for a root password. How would that be less secure than what Android currently does?

Comment: Although this is all correct, I still can't see how it answers the OP's question.

Comment: Generally speaking, this is the "modern" OS approach that seems to be taking off as of late. Specifically - each app operates within it's own sandboxed environment and file system - which is inaccessible to others. To goal is to make "ordinary" users unable to run root access software. Since most security exploits are - in one way or another - user errors.